# Show polygon on geotiff image in OpenLayers 7

Tags: javascript, openlayers, polygon, geotiff

I'm trying to plot a polygon on a geotiff image layer.
The code below work for just the polygon (on the OSMLayer) or the image (on the OSMLayer), but it doesn't work if i want to display it on the imageLayer.
The image projection is EPSG:4326 and the coords are in LonLat.
Does somebody know why it doesn't work?
I'm using Vue.js

Big thanks in advance!

```
async function addImage() {
    const source = await loadSource();
    const sourceView = await source.getView()
    const projection = sourceView.projection
    const epsgCode = projection.code_
 
    await fromEPSGCode(epsgCode);

    const newView = source.getView()

    const imageLayer = new WebGLTile({
        source: source,
    });

    map.value.addLayer(imageLayer)
    map.value.setView(newView);
}

function addPolygon() {
    // doesn't work with fromLonLat(coord, 'EPSG:4326')
    const openLayersCoords = polygonCoords.map(coord => fromLonLat(coord));
    // doesn't work with the polygonCoords as well
    const polygonGeometry = new Polygon([openLayersCoords]);
    const transformedGeometry = polygonGeometry.clone().transform('EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326')

    const polygonFeature = new Feature({
        type: "Polygon",
        geometry: transformedGeometry,
    });

    const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
        features: [polygonFeature],
    });

    const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
        source: vectorSource,
        style: new Style({
            stroke: new Stroke({
                color: 'red',
                width: 3,
            }),
        }),
    });

    map.value.addLayer(vectorLayer);
    map.value.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent(), {
        padding: [50, 50, 50, 50],
        maxZoom: 15,
    });
}

register(proj4);
const map = ref(null); // map object

const OSMlayer = new TileLayer({
    source: new OSM(),
});

async function loadSource() {
    const source = new GeoTIFF({
        sources: [
            {
                url: 'link-to-image',
            },
        ],
    });
    return source;
}

onMounted(async () => {
    map.value = new Map({
        target: "map",
        layers: [OSMlayer],
        view: new View({
            center: fromLonLat([10, 51]),
            zoom: 8,
        }),
    });
```

Comment: If the coordinates and EPSG:4326 and the view is EPSG:3857 then the geometry you need for the feature is `const transformedGeometry = new Polygon([polygonCoords]).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')`

Comment: @Mike Thanks you very much for for helping the people here with mine/their OpenLayers problems! :D
It turned out the source epsg was wrong in the meta data of the source image (which i created, therefore the projections cound't work. )
But now it is.